# How to add text boxes conditionally to answers in a Qualtrics' survey

Tags: qualtrics

I'm preparing a survey on Qualtrics. I need to ask to the customer the number of text boxes that will be displayed. For example:

```
Survey: "How many files do you use? Name them".
Customer: 5
```

And then 5 text boxes will be displayed in the survey. Does anyone know the answer? Please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to include the maximum number of possible text questions or text form rows, then use display logic on each to display the ones that apply.

You can't dynamically add text boxes (via JavaScript) because Qualtrics can't record what it doesn't know about.